# Aurora -> MySQL replication failing because of incompatible collation

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I am trying to replicate data from an Aurora MySQL instance running 5.7.12 to a MySQL database running Percona MySQL 5.7.35. The table character encoding is set to utf8 without a collation specified. `SHOW TABLE STATUS` on both databases show that the collation is `utf8_general_ci` for the table in question. Despite this, somehow replication is breaking with

```
Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Character set '#255' is not a compiled character set
```

where collation 255 is `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`:

```
| utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci         | utf8mb4 | 255 |         | Yes      |       0 |
```

Google results for this error indicate this is common when trying to replicate from 8.0 to 5.7, which is not the case here. Aurora further says that no variables are set to utf8mb4 at all:

```
mysql> show variables where value like '%utf8mb4%';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The collation and charset Aurora parameter group variables are unset, meaning that if it were somehow deciding that the table should use a utf8mb4 collation (which itself makes no sense, because again the table collation is `utf8_general_ci`), it should be using the system default, which on Aurora is

```
mysql> show collation where charset = 'utf8mb4';
+----------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
| Collation                  | Charset | Id  | Default | Compiled | Sortlen |
+----------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
| utf8mb4_general_ci         | utf8mb4 |  45 | Yes     | Yes      |       1 |
```

Where could Aurora be getting `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` as the collation for this table from?

Comment: Because utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci is the default collation for MySQL 8.0.

Comment: You apparently missed the part where this is not MySQL 8.0.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 does not have utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci.

Comment: Except that it apparently does, at least for Aurora 5.7. If Aurora is somehow lying about it's version number (and the defaults that it shows when queried) I would welcome information on how to get it to tell me the truth.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but have you managed to fix it? I'm facing the same issue and couldn't wrap my head around it. It is very weird how aurora deals with those internally.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since this was asked but I will still post, what needs to be done in order to resolve the issue.

This only applies to mysql client 8. When creating a table or modifying anything using this client it will default collation to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci as described here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html

This means that during the session, your mysql client sets the collation, not the server thus making that weird behavior you're seeing during the replication. You probably successfully connected the replica to AWS master and then tried to test it with a mysql client 8.0

The solution here is to install mysql client 5.7 and perform the tests with it.

Comment: This wasn't the problem. As it turned out, it was actually a bug in how RDS Proxy (which I didn't mention in the original post, because it didn't make sense that it could be contributing to the problem at the time) was handling writes to Aurora. TLDR AWS fixed that bug and my problems stopped.