# Cannot exporting data from an Aurora MySQL DB instance for replication

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm having some issues when trying to export binlog information and mysql dump with --master-data=1 from my Aurora MySQL instance. The error I'm receiving is

> "mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK': Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES) (1045)"

After some digging I found out that one way to do it is to create a read replica from the master, stop replication then perform the dump.

Sadly this does not work as I expected. In all AWS guides I've found they say to create a read replica from the "Actions" button, but I have no such option, doesn't even appear in the dropdown.

One option does appear, "Add a reader", which I did and after connecting to it, it seems like it's not a replica but more like a master with read only permissions, even if in the AWS console the "replica latency" column for that instance has a value attached to it.

It's a replica but it's not really a replica?

My main question here is how could I perform a dump of an Aurora MySQL in order to start replication on another instance?

I tried following most of the guides that are available from aws regarding mysql replication as well as lots of other stackoverflow questions.

Comment: What version of mysqldump are you using? You could have it right, but hitting a breaking on MySQL's side: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109685

Comment: @TomasButeler 

mysql  Ver 8.0.21 for macos10.15 on x86_64

But the real issue is when trying to dump an error pops-up regarding insufficient rights when performing FLUSH TABLE READ LOCK. Apparently when using Aurora, even if you are logged in as super user, you still don't have access to "super" commands... Hence why I tried to create a read replica, stop replication from master then perform the dump as their guides suggested: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/mysqldump-error-rds-mysql-mariadb/

Sadly this did not work. As there is no option to create read replica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick guide on migrating AWS MySQL 5.7 to Azure MySQL Flex 5.7 and what challenges I have encountered in order to help other people with this as well.

1. Create a new database from a snapshot taken from the master in AWS RDS with the bin_log parameter group enabled. This will now act as our new "fakeMaster". I will refer to it as "fakeMaster" from this point on.
2. Create a replication user on your master

```
CREATE USER 'replication-user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<repl-user-password>';
GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replication-user';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

3. Get bin log information from the master

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

4. Get bin log details from your fakeMaster

```
SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

Correlate the binlog log name from your master with one of the results from the fakeMaster. This way you will find the bin log position. Copy the log_name and position from your fakeMaster, you will need them later.

5. Make a full dump of the fakeMaster

```
mysqldump -h <name>.<region>.rds.amazonaws.com -u <user> -p<password> --routines --column-statistics=0 <dbname> > dump.sql
```

`--column-statistics=0` is required only if you have MySQL version 8 installed

6. If you performed the dump with MySQL client version 8, delete the following lines from `dump.sql`, otherwise skip this step.

Those should be at the very top of the file

```
​​SET @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN = @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN;
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;

--
-- GTID state at the beginning of the backup
--

SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ 'someid';
```

This should be at the very end of the file

```
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN = @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN;
```

7. Power up your replica on Azure. If gtid_mode is enabled on your master (AWS), make sure your replica also has it enabled. This comes by default on HA(high availability) but if you're just testing things out you need to do the following extra steps to enable it.

   7.1 Change the setting of “enforce_gtid_consistency” to ON and save the setting.

   7.2 Change the setting of “gtid_mode” from OFF to OFF_PERMISSIVE  and save the setting.

   7.3 Change the setting of “gtid_mode” from OFF_PERMISSIVE  to ON_PERMISSIVE  and save the setting.

   7.4 Change the setting of “gtid_mode” from ON_PERMISSIVE  to ON and save the setting.
8. Import dump from AWS fakemMaster to Azure replica

```
cat dump.sql | mysql -h <host>.mysql.database.azure.com -u <user> -p<password> <db-name>
```

9. Change master on Azure replica

Resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/how-to-data-in-replication?tabs=command-line#link-source-and-replica-servers-to-start-data-in-replication

```
CALL mysql.az_replication_change_master('<host>.<region>.rds.amazonaws.com', 'replication-user', '<replication-user-password>', 3306, '<bin-log-file-from-step-4>', <bin-log-position-from-step-4>, <certificate-if-any>);
```

10. Start replication

```
CALL mysql.az_replication_start;
```

11. Check status

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;
```

Here are a few useful commands in case you need:

- Stop replication

```
CALL mysql.az_replication_stop;
```

- Remove master

```
CALL mysql.az_replication_remove_master;
```

- Import timezone database

```
CALL mysql.az_load_timezone();
```

**Important to know:** When testing things out make sure you are using MySQL client version 5.7 otherwise you would end up with something similar to this question:

[Aurora -> MySQL replication failing because of incompatible collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73463383/aurora-mysql-replication-failing-because-of-incompatible-collation/75522750#75522750)

Other useful links you might want to read before or during replication:

**Replication requirements:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/concepts-data-in-replication#requirements

**High overview of replication to azure:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/how-to-data-in-replication?tabs=command-line

**VPN Peering:** https://infra.engineer/azure/52-site-to-site-vpn-between-aws-and-azure

For VPN peering, remember to allow the Azure local IP for inbound connections on port 3306 to your AWS database security group.

Using the VPN Site-To-Site you can safely perform replications without exposing any of the databases to the internet.

Answer (score -1):

There is an unfortunate overloading of "replica" here.

read replica = some non-Aurora MySQL server (RDS or on-premises) that you replicate to.

Aurora replica = the 2nd, 3rd, and so on DB instance in an Aurora cluster. Read-only. Gets notified of data changes by an entirely different mechanism than binlog replication. Thus this term is phased out in favor of "reader instance", but you will still see it lurking in documentation that compares and contrasts different ways to do replication.

Aurora read replica = a read-only Aurora cluster that gets data replicated *into* it via binlog from some other source.

If you select an RDS MySQL instance in the console, that has an option to create a read replica, because that's the only kind of replication it can do. Aurora MySQL clusters only have "add reader"* because that is the most common / fastest / most efficient way for Aurora. The instructions here cover all the different permutations:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.html

That page recommends using a snapshot as the initial "dump" from the Aurora cluster.

- There is also an option "Create cross-Region read replica" for Aurora clusters. But for that capability, it's preferable to do "Add AWS Region" instead - that uses an Aurora-specific mechanism (Aurora global database) to do low-latency replication between AWS Regions.